# Call a function after ajax is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Here is a function which does an ajax call

```
function gettrans(callback) {
  var xml = $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'url/?callback=jsonpCallback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: !1,
    jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback",
    data: { drop_lang: dropjslang,},
    success: function (data) {
      callback();
    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
  });
  return xml.responseJSON
}
```

I want to return `xml.responseJSON` but I get `undefined`.

What may be a solution?

Comment: You can't return a value synchronously if the value itself is fetched/produced asynchronously. `$.ajax` call is asynchronous so `gettrans` cannot return a value synchronously. You can return a promise. Or you can make the ajax call upfornt and have the success call back set the value/data which you can return using gettrans, Welcome to asynchronous programming !

Answer (score 2):

Pass the result to your callback:

```
function gettrans(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function (data) {
      callback(data);
    },
    ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to pass a callback function in `success`:

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response); // response is the data returned by your ajax query
}
```